# 'UTF-8 codec can't decode byte 0xfc: invalid start byte - load_model (keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I have been trying to create an easy chatbot. Here is the code aka training.py:

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignoreLetters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        wordList = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wordList)
        documents.append((wordList, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignoreLetters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

training = []
outputEmpty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    wordPatterns = document[0]
    wordPatterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in wordPatterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in wordPatterns else bag.append(0)

    outputRow = list(outputEmpty)
    outputRow[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append(bag + outputRow)

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

trainX = training[:, :len(words)]
trainY = training[:, len(words):]

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(len(trainX[0]),), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(trainY[0]), activation='softmax'))

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbot.h5')
print('Done')
```

And here is the code aka main.py for making the chatbot work:

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from keras.models import load_model

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbot.h5')

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

def bag_of_words(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)

def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bag_of_words(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]

    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({'intent': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])})
    return return_list

def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result

print("Go! Bot is running!")

while True: 
    message = input("")
    ints = predict_class(message)
    res = get_response(ints, intents)
    print(res)
```

When I try to execute main.py this error pops up:

C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/User/source/repos/ai/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User\source\repos\ai\main.py", line 15, in 
model = load_model('chatbot.h5')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saving_api.py", line 212, in load_model
return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 703, in is_directory_v2
return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 31: invalid start byte

The training.py works as expected and saves the words and classes in pkl files. But I just can't make the load.model work. I jhave seen that there were others with a similar problem but that didn't work out for me.

Comment: is it possible for you to share `chatbot.h5`?

Comment: @AliEnt Its too long to share but do you just need the first few lines?

Comment: I wanted to check if the problem is with the file or your tensorflow and keras version.

Comment: @AliEnt So I installed Tensorflow just with the comand pip install tensorflow. And I cant copy the code so I dont know.

Comment: Did you managed to solve the problem? I am having the same issue. Trained my network, saved into a `.hdf5` file, but trying to use `load_model()` into it and running to a similar issue:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 26: invalid start byte`

Comment: I also have this problem, and I can not solve :  pycharm says -
model = keras.models.load_model('model_checkpoints/best_model.h5')
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 17: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Hey, @CodeFaber I posted my solution and what I changed. I hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made and it worked for me!

```
model.save('chatbot.h5', save_format='h5')
```

And here the main.py for the chatbot:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('chatbot.h5', compile=True)
```

I hope this helps for you!

Answer (score 0):

This two solution worked for me. The second one, keeps the model format in h5.

1 - Change model format:

```
model.save('chatbot.keras')
model = load_model('chatbot.keras')
```

2 - Uninstall h5py and install again.

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pickle instead of HDF5 for the following reason: Pickle module allows you to save trained AI models without the error of decode byte encountered in HDF5 since a while ago. And also remember this:

```
res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
```

You used model once in this line of code. Hence, the only reason why you saved in .h5 file is due to that line of code. Therefore, you should replace these two lines:

From training.py:

```
model.save('chatbot.h5')
```

with:

```
pickle.dump(model, open('chatbot.pkl', 'wb'))
```

And from chatbot.py:

```
model = load_model('chatbot.h5')
```

with:

```
model = pickle.load(open('chatbot.pkl', 'rb'))
```

And then you are ready to go!